# Obter elemento anterior em foreach

Tags: c#, .net, loop

É possível pegar um elemento da posição anterior a atual usando o laço de repetição `foreach`?

Por exemplo, sempre que preciso pegar um elemento anterior ao da posição atual do laço, uso o laço de repetição `for`, como a seguir:

```
List<int> ListaDados = new List<int>();

ListaDados.Add(1); ListaDados.Add(2); ListaDados.Add(3); ListaDados.Add(5);

for(int i=1; i < ListaDados.Count; i++) {      
    var elementoAtual = ListaDados[i];
    var elementoAnterior = ListaDados[i-1];
}
```

Comment: Não, por definição o foreach vai invocar o IEnumerable.GetEnumerator para fazer a sua incrementação, ele não utiliza o index como o FOR.

Comment: Só como detalhe, este código daria erro de execução na primeira iteração do _for_, já que não existe elemento na posição `-1` da `ListaDados`

Comment: Usar um `for` comum é de longe a melhor solução.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sim, é possível:

```
using static System.Console;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var lista = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
        var anterior = 0;
        foreach (var item in lista) {
            WriteLine($"Soma o atual e anterior { anterior + item }");
            anterior = item;
        }
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/gjebuw). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LI3Sz5). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Collection/PreviousItem.cs).

A forma exata de como implementar isso depende da sua necessidade. Em alguns casos pode ser interessante colocar uma comparação para evitar a primeira execução, já que C# não trata essa execução de forma diferente e nem pretendem ter isto na linguagem.

Em estruturas que você cria ou pode estender é possível criar um enumerador específico que te dê acesso ao elemento anterior, mas isso é outra questão.

Não gosto da outra resposta, ela é absurdamente mais lenta, com complexidade possivelmente quadrática (em [`List`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=net-5.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) certamente, e é em dobro). E acho que até está errada porque se tiver itens duplicados vai dar erro.

Answer (score 0):

Como o Gabriel comentou, *"por definição o **foreach** vai invocar o **IEnumerable.GetEnumerator** para fazer a sua incrementação, ele não utiliza o index como o **for**"*.

Mas existe uma alternativa (que eu acredito não ser muito viável) caso queira mesmo utilizar o *foreach*:

```
List<int> ListaDados = new List<int>();

ListaDados.Add(1); ListaDados.Add(2); ListaDados.Add(3); ListaDados.Add(5);

freach (int elementoAtual in ListaDados){

    if (ListaDados.IndexOf(elementoAtual) == 0)
        // não existe elemento anterior
    else
    {
        var elementoAnterior = ListaDados.ElementAt(ListaDados.IndexOf(elementoAtual));

        //todo: seu código
    }
}
```

Comment: Leia minha edição, não analisei profundamente, se quiser pode contestar. Não falei da possibilidade de ter um um elemento atual que seja 0, e executará o primeiro como se tivesse um anterior. Isso na verdade não deixa de ser o mesmo problema de ter duplicados e pode ser que em algum uso não seja problema, conforme falo na resposta. Na minha teria se ñ for uma soma talvez precise usar uma *flag* ou outro mecanismo para tratar o primeiro, então nesse ponto não chega ser um erro na sua resposta.